# Inheritance issues with template classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

Can anyone figure out a nice way to get the following code to work? (This is, once again, an incredibly simplified way of doing this)

template <class f, class g> class Ptr;

class RealBase
{
};

template <class a, class b, class c = Ptr<a,b> >
class Base : public RealBase
{
public:
    Base(){};
};

template <class d, class e>
class Derived : public Base <d,e>
{
public:
    Derived(){};
    void DerivedMethod(){};
};
template <class f, class g>
class Ptr
{
public:
    Ptr(){};
    Ptr(Base<f,g,Ptr<f,g> >* a){in = a;};
    Base<f,g,Ptr<f,g> >* operator->()
    {
        return in;
    };
private:
    Base<f,g,Ptr<f,g> >* in;
};

typedef Derived<double,double> DDerived;

int main()
{
    Base<int,int> b = Base<int,int>();
    Derived<double,double> d = Derived<double,double>();
    DDerived dd = DDerived();
    Ptr<double,double> p(&dd);
    p->DerivedMethod();
    return 1;
}

At the moment the compiler moans because a Base<> doesn't have a DerivedMethod();

EDIT

I do understand the problem here, my bad for a lack of explanation in the first case (I was in a rush). [This is very cut down code by the way so, yes, for the sake of simplicity I don't have destructors or methods that actually DO anything. Just ignore that, it makes no difference to the problem.]

What I need to happen is that an iterator (that isn't detailed here) that deals only with the derived class (D_Derived) need to access a method that is contained within a derived class and not the base class. Simply plonking this method into the base class isn't really an option because this error is going to occur a LOT if I have to do that. (There are about 10 classes built on the real base class, and they all have derived methods of their own. Like 20 of them. Each.)

Can anyone think of another way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. After trying about 10 different methods (`static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` etc.) you can just cast it.

```
int main()
{
    Base&lt;int,int> b = Base&lt;int,int>();
    Derived&lt;double,double> d = Derived&lt;double,double>();
    DDerived dd = DDerived();
    Ptr&lt;double,double> p(&dd);
    DDerived * fauxpointer;
    fauxpointer = (DDerived\*) &(*p);
    fauxpointer->DerivedMethod();
    return 1;
}
```

Nasty. But it works, and that's all that counts.

Cheers to everyone who repeated the question back at me.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't work because template class Ptr returns the object of Class of Base Template not Class of Derived Template. Derived Method is part of derived template so this throws compilation error. Whereas if DerivedMethod was part of Base Template this code will work

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense. Base doesn't have such a method (DerivedMethod). If DerivedMethod were a virtual function (could be `pure`) of the base class it'd work.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right. In order for you to be able to access a method, this method must be declared in the type that the compiler sees (this is called the *static type* of a variable). In your case, this type is `Base<…>` and the compiler has no clue that it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to figure out what you actually want to achieve, using your abstract class and member names. If you really have to treat the pointer within `Ptr` as a `D_Derived`, add an accessor member to `Ptr` and use type casting:

```
class Ptr {
    ...

    Base<f,g,Ptr<f,g> >* get() {
        return in;
    }
};

...

D_Derived* ptr = dynamic_cast<D_Derived*>(p.get());
if (ptr) {
    ptr->DerivedMethod();
}
```

---

**EDIT**: As Konrad Rudolph pointed out, in order to use dynamic casting, you will have to add a virtual method to your base class.

Actually it is a good practice to define a virtual destructor for every class that you want to use as a base class anyway, to ensure the destructor of your derived class will be called ([More Information](http://www.codersource.net/cpp_virtual_destructors.html)).

```
class RealBase {
public:
    virtual ~RealBase() {}
};
```

Comment: You cannot use the `dyanmic_cast` here! The class has no virtual member, hence no runtime type information!

Comment: You are right, I missed that point. Edited my original post -- thanks.

Comment: N.B. There are a very large number of methods missing in this code, and it's all named very simply to aid understanding. They all have destructors really.

Comment: If they all have destructors, than it is really essential to declare them *virtual*, if you haven't already done that!

Comment: Ahem. IRRELEVANT. This was example code. I'm not asking for tips on my coding style, I know what I'm doing, as a general rule. What I'm asking for is a way of doing what I'm demonstrating above.

Comment: You are saying that you need to extract the DDerived specialization from Ptr and pass it to some iterator. If I understand correctly, you will need to up-cast it using dynamic casting, as I described above. Otherwise I still don't get your problem!